# Android Studio created a activity,but the EditText with color border

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, android-edittext

[image]

this is the screenprint of app
my android studio is v2.2 preview 2

Comment: please post your xml file .

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are using custom background images for your views, its like a 9-patch image but not rendered properly. if you have used a background attribute in your view, remove it and see results. I could have given a better answer seeing the xml.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I find this due to my phone, I use other phone,it works without problem.